# Generating Pseudo data for analysis

Tags: r, linux, bash, paste, shuffle

I am trying to generate pseudo data to perform some analysis. i want to shuffle 
first 6 columns and then attach them with column 7 onward.

a small sample file work fine with the script and give me the desired output

but when i put a file with 1000 rows and 8644482 columns the command never finish
 with this script.

i read on this forum that for bigdata i can use

```
# install.packages("data.table")

library(data.table)

fread("bigDataFile.txt")
```

it gave this error

```
possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection: 2
```

Input File:

```
B01 1 0 0 1 -9 C C G G A G
B04 4 0 0 1 -9 C C G G A G
B40 40 0 0 1 -9 T C G G A G
B50 50 0 0 1 -9 T C G G A G
B73 73 0 0 1 -9 C C G G A A
B78 78 0 0 2 -9 C C G G A G
B86 86 0 0 2 -9 T C A A A G
B92 92 0 0 1 -9 T C A G 0 0
B93 93 0 0 2 -9 C C A G A G
B94 94 0 0 2 -9 T C G G G G
```

output

```
B40 40 0 0 1 -9 C C G G A G
B93 93 0 0 2 -9 C C G G A G
B01 1 0 0 1 -9 T C G G A G
B92 92 0 0 1 -9 T C G G A G
B04 4 0 0 1 -9 C C G G A A
B86 86 0 0 2 -9 C C G G A G
B73 73 0 0 1 -9 T C A A A G
B78 78 0 0 2 -9 T C A G 0 0
B94 94 0 0 2 -9 C C A G A G
B50 50 0 0 1 -9 T C G G G G
```

Commands used:

```
x <- read.table("genotypeSample.txt",sep="")

> y <- c(x[sample(1:nrow(x)),1:6], x[,7:12])

> write.table(y,"shufx.txt",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE, quote=F)
```

Beside the big file issue if i want to create 100 different file with this script how to use this script in loop.

I also tried Linux command to achieve this. 
in linux Shuf -generate random permutations

```
cut -d" " -f1-6 genotypeSample.txt |shuf > a.txt

paste -d" " a.txt <(cut -d" " -f7- genotypeSample.txt)
```

for loop with test fine but how can I use shuf to generate 100 random permutations

```
for i in {1..100};do cut -d" " -f1-6 genotypeSample.txt |shuf  > a${i}.txt ;done

for i in {1..100}; do paste -d" " a${i}.txt <(cut -d" " -f7- genotypeSample.txt) > a$i.dat  ; done
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you can do the cutting once; also eliminate intermediate files, should speed up some.

```
cut -d' ' -f1-6 genotypeSample.txt > a
cut -d' ' -f7-  genotypeSample.txt > b

for i in {1..100}; 
do 
    paste -d' ' <(shuf a) b > a$i.dat;
done
```

**ps.** Not tested!